# Inequality problem

Tags: calculus, inequality

$$|x|^{x^2-x-2}<1$$
I tried to do this problem by taking different cases like first taking $x$ and then $-x$.
For $+x$, the exponent should be less than $1$ so that the whole thing becomes a fraction hence lesser than $1$.
For 2nd cases, I'm confused what cases to take.
Help is appreciated!

Comment: This site uses Latex for typesetting.Refer to this link for proper formatting of mathematical statements-http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: You should consider two cases: $|x|<1$ and $|x|>1$.

Comment: It's easier if you take logarithms. The inequality now becomes $ (x^2-x-2) \log |x| < 0$ or $(x-2)(x+1) \log |x| < 0$. A product of three terms is negative if either all three or exactly one term is negative. Now consider cases.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=|x|^{x^2-x-2}=|x|^{(x+1)(x-2)}$$ It follows that $f(x)=1$ when $x=-1,1,2$ You can verify that $-1$ correspond to a minimun, that a second minimun is between $1$ and $2$ and there is not another one. Hence, by continuity, you have as answer the open interval $$1\lt x\lt2$$